# Dynamic keys in fat-free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

In order to access an array that has been created in a php script on an html page, we do this `{{@somearray['somevalue']}}`.

How do we deal with a situation where the key (`'somevalue'`) is to be obtained from some other array `{{@someotherarray['someotherindex'}}` 

( i.e. the value at `{{@someotherarray['someotherindex']}}` = `somevalue`)?

I am using F3 version 2.1.x.

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried `{{@somearray[{{@someotherarray['someotherindex']}}]}}` ?

Comment: Yes sir. The output to the browser is ` ] }}`.

Comment: Another guess :P `{{@index = @someotherarray['someotherindex']}}
{{@somearray[@index]}}`

Comment: as a workaround in v2, you could set new vars in template with `{{F3::set('somevalue',F3::get('someotherarray.someotherindex'))}}`

Comment: Downvoter please explain.

Comment: Deleting this question because the community does not seem to like it. There have been downvotes without explanation.... Very strange to see that the question is downvoted yet the answer is upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in 3.x and doesn't work in 2.x.

Syntax in 3.x is: `{{@arr1.@arr2.@field}}`

Comment: I adopted a different approach altogether by changing the business logic. Thanks for the answer :)